# Why is Flex:Direction not working in CSS/Flask

Tags: html, css

I have a simple UI setup and I want to get all elements working horizontally.
When I use the below code the lower of the two sections always works horizontal, but the top is always stacked.  If I add a third exact copy the second and third elements will be right but the top one is always vertical. Even if I copy the exact same code two or three times in separate divs.

```
<!--Flags-->

<div class="tags" style="padding: 0% 5 0 0; display:flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: center; align-items: center">
    <form method="get">
    
    <p>
        <b><label for="flags">Include</label></b>
    </p>
    
    <p>
        <input id="flags-1" name="flags" type="checkbox" value="Sex">
        <label for="flags-1">Sex & Nudity</label>
    </p>

    
    <p>
        <input id="flags-2" name="flags" type="checkbox" value="Drugs">
        <label for="flags-2">Drugs,Alcohol & Smoking</label>
    </p>
    
    <p>
        <input id="flags-3" name="flags" type="checkbox" value="Violence">
        <label for="flags-3">Violence & Gore</label>
    </p>
    
    <p>
        <input id="flags-4" name="flags" type="checkbox" value="Profanity">
        <label for="flags-4">Profanity</label>
    </p>
    
</div>

<br>

<div class="tags" style="padding: 0% 5 0 0; display:flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: center; align-items: center">
    <form method="get">
    <p>
        <b><label for="flags">Exclude</label></b>
    </p>
    
        <p>
            <input id="flags-1" name="flags" type="checkbox" value="Sex">
            <label for="flags-1">Sex & Nudity</label>
        </p>
        
        <p>
            <input id="flags-2" name="flags" type="checkbox" value="Drugs">
            <label for="flags-2">Drugs,Alcohol & Smoking</label>
        </p>
        
        <p>
            <input id="flags-3" name="flags" type="checkbox" value="Violence">
            <label for="flags-3">Violence & Gore</label>
        </p>
                
        <p>
            <input id="flags-4" name="flags" type="checkbox" value="Profanity">
            <label for="flags-4">Profanity</label>
        </p>
        
</div>

<!--End Flags-->
```

[image: vertical and horizontal divs]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inconsistency is happening because you aren't closing your `<form>` tags. If you want the form to layout horizontally, move the flex box code to the `<form>` tag and close the form after your menu options.

When you set the flex options on the div, you are saying "center the `<form>` within this `<div>`" but when you set it at the `<form>` tag level you are saying "center the `<p>` tags as a row within the form"

```
<!--Flags-->

<div >
    <form class="tags" style="padding: 0% 5 0 0; display:flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: center; align-items: center" method="get">
    
    <p>
        <b><label for="flags">Include</label></b>
    </p>
    
    <p>
        <input id="flags-1" name="flags" type="checkbox" value="Sex">
        <label for="flags-1">Sex & Nudity</label>
    </p>

    
    <p>
        <input id="flags-2" name="flags" type="checkbox" value="Drugs">
        <label for="flags-2">Drugs,Alcohol & Smoking</label>
    </p>
    
    <p>
        <input id="flags-3" name="flags" type="checkbox" value="Violence">
        <label for="flags-3">Violence & Gore</label>
    </p>
    
    <p>
        <input id="flags-4" name="flags" type="checkbox" value="Profanity">
        <label for="flags-4">Profanity</label>
    </p>
    </form>
</div>

<br>

<div >
    <form class="tags" style="padding: 0% 5 0 0; display:flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: center; align-items: center" method="get">
    
    <p>
        <b><label for="flags">Include</label></b>
    </p>
    
    <p>
        <input id="flags-1" name="flags" type="checkbox" value="Sex">
        <label for="flags-1">Sex & Nudity</label>
    </p>

    
    <p>
        <input id="flags-2" name="flags" type="checkbox" value="Drugs">
        <label for="flags-2">Drugs,Alcohol & Smoking</label>
    </p>
    
    <p>
        <input id="flags-3" name="flags" type="checkbox" value="Violence">
        <label for="flags-3">Violence & Gore</label>
    </p>
    
    <p>
        <input id="flags-4" name="flags" type="checkbox" value="Profanity">
        <label for="flags-4">Profanity</label>
    </p>
    </form>
</div>



<!--End Flags-->
```